# Spring Security: Multiple http elements with Multiple AuthenticationManagers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am struggling with Java Config for Spring Security. I have multiple entry points but I cannot get the `AuthenticationManager`s provisioned correctly.

My first configuration file is like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(100)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .antMatcher("/service/**")
            .addFilterAfter(requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/service/**").authenticated()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider(null));
    }

@Bean
public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception
{
    // Takes the value of the specified header as the user principal
    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("SECRET_HEADER");
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
    return filter;
}
```

This all works correctly.  When I set a breakpoint in the `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` I see an `AuthenticationManager` with one `AuthenticationProvider`, and that is the `preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` (not shown because is just a regular old bean).

I also have a special security chain for admin users and the like:

```
@Configuration
@Order(101)
public class AdminSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .authenticationProvider(mainSiteLoginAuthenticationProvider())
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("SECRET ADMIN ACCESS EXPRESSION")
                .antMatchers("/internal/**").access("SECRET INTERNAL ACCESS EXPRESSION")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/thing")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/do_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/thing")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                //.authenticationEntryPoint(null) // entry-point-ref="loginEntryPoint"
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)  // create-session="ifRequired"
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
```

This is now working (after a lot of struggle), but if I put a breakpoint in the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, I see that this filter has a different `AuthenticationManager` instance, which is provisioned with the `mainSiteLoginAuthenticationProvider` as expected.  However, it has a *parent* `AuthenticationManager` which is provisioned with the default `DaoAuthenticationProvider` that generates a temporary password in the logs:

```
Using default security password: 47032daf-813e-4da1-a224-b6014a705805
```

So my questions are:

- How can I get both security configs to use the same `AuthenticationManager`? I thought that the `SecurityConfig`, being order 100, would create one, and then `AdminConfig`, being 101, would just use it. But I have been unable to get them to use the same `AuthenticationManager`.
- Failing that, how can I prevent the `AuthenticationManger` of `AdminConfig` from generating a parent that has the default `DaoAuthenticationProvider`?

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE, which means Spring Security 4.2.3.RELEASE.

Comment: You first configuration builds a local `AuthenticationManger`. You have to expose it to use it in a different configuration. Your second configuration builds no `AuthenticationManager`, so it uses the global `AuthenticationManager`.

Comment: How does one expose the local authentication manager?  And how to get the other config to use it?